# SQL Foreign Key Issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting an issue with MySQL for a seeming simple addition of a foreign key. I asked Google, but to no avail. Here goes:

Create first table with:

```
| users | CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `firstname` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Create second table with:

```
| contacts | CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `username` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phonenumber` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Now I need to add a foreign key which links 'contacts' with 'users'.

```
ALTER TABLE contacts ADD FOREIGN KEY (username) references USERS(username));
```

But I get this error:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

The objective is obviously to ensure that all entries in 'contacts' have a corresponding 'username' entry in 'users'.

Environment: Ubuntu 11.04, MySQL 5.1.58

I must be making a stupid mistake somewhere. Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, change the engine of these 2 table from `MyISAM` to `InnoDB`. MyISAM does not support `FOREIGN KEY` constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE users
ENGINE = InnoDB ;

ALTER TABLE contacts
ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

Then add the `FOREIGN KEY`, removing the extra parenthesis. There are 2 ways to do this. With the code you had, that will automatically add an index (key) on column `username`:

```
ALTER TABLE contacts 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (username) 
    REFERENCES users(username);
```

Or explictedly adding the Index (Key) yourself and the Foreign Key constraint (you also choose the names of the index and constraint yourself):

```
ALTER TABLE contacts 
  ADD KEY username_ie (username),
  ADD CONSTRAINT users_contacts_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (username) 
    REFERENCES users(username);
```

Comment: This turned out to be the actual solution. Thank you ypercube.

Comment: The solution: MyISAM does not support foreign keys. Made that InnoDB. Also, there were 2 syntax errors in the above ALTER table statement. It should read:

    ALTER TABLE contacts ADD CONSTRAINT 
    FOREIGN KEY (username) references users(username);

Watch for braces and lower-case table name. Problem solved. Thanks guys. Love this stackoverflow.

Comment: @sphere74: Table names case-sensitivity (or not) depends on installation settings: [Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: Thanks ypercube. I was totally wondering... about how MySQL was being case sensitive when SQL-99 is specified to not be case sensitive.

Comment: How various DBMSs treat case sensitivity on identifiers: [Database identifiers, quoting and case sensitivity](http://www.alberton.info/dbms_identifiers_and_case_sensitivity.html)

Answer (score 5):

```
ALTER TABLE contacts ADD FOREIGN KEY (username) references USERS(username));
```

You have an extra parenthesis at end of the line.

should be

```
ALTER TABLE contacts ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (username) references USERS(username);
```

Comment: Super... Good catch... Thank you Sathya